# $|x-1| +|x+1| <1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you help me with this inequality?

$|x-1| +|x+1| <1$.

I think that it doesn't exist an $x$ that satisfies this inequality, but I'm not really convinced about my answer.

Comment: The inequality reads: "The sum of the distances from $x$ to $-1$ and $1$ is less than $1$."  This can't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $|a|=a$, if $a\ge 0$ and $|a|=-a$ if $a<0.$

1) If $x<-1$, then $|x-1|+|x+1|=1-x-x-1<1$
$$-2x<1$$
$$x>-\frac12$$
But $-1>x$

2) $-1\le x \le 1$

Similarly

3) $x>1$

Similarly

Answer (score 3):

Note that $|y|\geq y$ implies that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$| x-1| +| x+1|=| 1-x| +|x+1|\geq (1-x)+(x+1)\geq 2.$$
Hence $| 1-x| +|x+1|<1$ is never satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There is no such $x$.

If $x\geq 0$, then the distance from $x$ to $-1$ is $\geq 1$. I.e., $|x-(-1)|=|x+1|\geq 1$.

Similarly, if $x<0$, then the distance from $x$ to $1$ is $> 1$. I.e., $|x-1|> 1$.

Therefore, for all $x$, $|x-1|+|x+1|\geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand it better one way is to plot y=abs(x-1)+abs(x+1) and y=1 and then you can obtain the answer, y is something like this:
[Click to see the figure](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dabs(x-1)%2Babs(x%2B1))