# $|x-1|\cdot|x+1|=0$ and $|x-1|\cdot|x+2|=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Can you help me with these equations?
$$|x-1|\cdot |x+1|=0$$
$$|x-1|\cdot |x+2|=3$$
I don't know how to solve them.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint $ab=0$ implies that either $a=0$, $b=0$, or both.

Comment: You can use the sign method that has been explained in [your other quesrion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917803/x-1-x1-1)

Comment: I don't think the edit to remove the i) and ii) helped. Previously, it seemed like they were two different problems, each with two solutions. Now it seems like there's one problem, with no solutions. It also made the answers that reference i) and ii) more confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

For ii), I would use this:

- $\lvert A\rvert \lvert B\rvert= \lvert A B\rvert$,
- $\lvert A\rvert=a \;(\ge0)\iff (A =a\;\text{or}\;A=-a)$.

Answer (score 0):

(i) $|x-1|=0$ or $|x+1|=0$

Then $x=\pm1$

(ii)

1)If $x<-2$ then $|x-1|\cdot|x+2|=-(x-1)\cdot(-(x+2))$. Then 
$$(x-1)(x+2)=3$$
$$x^2+x-5=0$$

2) $-2\le x \le 1$. Similarly

3) $x> 1$. Similarly

Answer (score 0):

i) $|x-1|\cdot |x+1|=0$ iff $|x-1|=0$ or $|x+1|=0$ that is $x\in\{1,-1\}$

ii) $|x-1|\cdot |x+2|=|(x-1)(x+2)|=3$ which is equivalent to solve the quadratic equations $(x-1)(x+2)=3$ or $(x-1)(x+2)=-3$. The first equation has two solutions, namely $(-1\pm \sqrt{21})/2$ and the second one none. So the solutions of ii) are $(-1\pm \sqrt{21})/2$.